# CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found while rendering files using blender on GPU

Tags: blender

System Information: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, GTX 1080, CUDA 10.1, Blender 2.79b

I am trying to render around 10000 images using the code at `https://github.com/facebookresearch/clevr-dataset-gen`. It worked out of the box but after rendering around 700 images it repeatedly outputs the following message and doesn't render anything.

```
Fra:1 Mem:17.54M (0.00M, Peak 17.54M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Area
Fra:1 Mem:17.54M (0.00M, Peak 17.54M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Ground
Fra:1 Mem:17.60M (0.00M, Peak 17.86M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Empty
Fra:1 Mem:17.60M (0.00M, Peak 17.86M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Back
Fra:1 Mem:17.60M (0.00M, Peak 17.86M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Fill
Fra:1 Mem:17.60M (0.00M, Peak 17.86M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Key
Fra:1 Mem:17.60M (0.00M, Peak 17.86M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Camera
Fra:1 Mem:17.60M (0.00M, Peak 17.86M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | SmoothCylinder_0
Fra:1 Mem:20.38M (0.00M, Peak 23.60M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Sphere_0
Fra:1 Mem:21.64M (0.00M, Peak 23.60M) | Time:00:00.09 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Sphere_1
Fra:1 Mem:22.90M (0.00M, Peak 24.40M) | Time:00:00.09 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | SmoothCylinder_1
Fra:1 Mem:26.22M (0.00M, Peak 29.31M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | SmoothCube_v2_0
Fra:1 Mem:26.53M (0.00M, Peak 29.31M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Initializing
Fra:1 Mem:26.53M (0.00M, Peak 29.31M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)
CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found

Refer to the Cycles GPU rendering documentation for possible solutions:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Failed loading CUDA kernel /home/name/Downloads/rendering_software/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/scripts/addons/cycles/lib/kernel_sm_61.cubin.
CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Failed loading CUDA kernel /home/name/Downloads/rendering_software/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/scripts/addons/cycles/lib/filter_sm_61.cubin.
Fra:1 Mem:26.53M (0.00M, Peak 29.31M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Error | CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Error: CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Fra:1 Mem:26.53M (0.00M, Peak 29.31M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Waiting for render to start
Fra:1 Mem:26.53M (0.00M, Peak 29.31M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderLayer | Cancel | CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Fra:1 Mem:17.53M (0.00M, Peak 29.31M) | Time:00:00.16 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Error: CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Error: CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
```

Comment: First of all the error says it can't find `/home/name/Downloads/rendering_software/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/scripts/addons/cycles/lib/kernel_sm_61.cubin` - is that path part of the **running copy** of blender installation? If the path is correct but `kernel_sm_61.cubin` is not there, do you have the cuda sdk installed? The `nvcc` installed by the sdk should compile `kernel.cu` to match the GPU. Was gpu rendering actually working on previous renders? Maybe the first ones used CPU.

Comment: @sambler Yes, the `kernel_sm_61.cubin` file is present at the given location. I have cuda sdk installed. Also, I ran it again to check whether the rendering was done by GPU or not and it was. I found this by looking at the process running on the GPU and whether it was using GPU memory or not.